# Getting values out of a struct which is a type for a class

Tags: c++, templates

This is what my code looks like.  It is a bit simplified.  What I'm trying to/wondering if i can do is eliminate the need for the argument in the property class constructor.  i.e. call a no arg constructor and still be able to populate the classes item variable with the struct value1 item variable without adding them as part of the constructors body.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct value1
{
    const int item;
    value1( int n ) : item(n) { }
};

struct value2 : public value1
{
    value2() : value1(55) { };
};

template <class T>
class property
{
public:
    property(T stuff);
    void print();
private:
    int item;
};

template <class T>
property<T>::property(T stuff) : item(stuff.item) { }

template <class T>
void property<T>::print()
{
    cout << item << endl;
}

int main()
{
    property<value2> *y = new property<value2>(value2());

    y->print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: so you just want to set up a default constructor that initializes the members of the object?

Comment: yes, but without initializing the object in the body of the constructor

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you are asking. You use a constructor to create  an instance of an object. you don't initialize an object in the body of a constructor. you initiallize the members of an object there.

Comment: I don't understand either. Could you please add to the question some desired example code? For instance: is it something like: `property<value2> *y = new property<value2>(); y->item = value2().item`? Or something like: `property<value2> *y = new property(value2());`?

Comment: What I was going for is if there is a way to get the values in the type without initializing an object.  Now I'm pretty sure that's not possible. I think the right way to do it is in the constructor like this    Property<T>::Property() { T val = T(); item = val.item }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> call a no arg constructor and still be able to populate the classes item variable with the struct value1 item variable without adding them as part of the constructors body

It sounds like you simply want a factory method:

```
template <class T>
class property {
public:
    property();
    void print();

    static property<T> create(T stuff) {
        property<T> p;
        p.item = stuff.item;
        return p;
    }

private:
    int item;
};
```

You can invoke it as it follows:

```
auto p = property<value2>::create(value2());
```

Even if I'm not sure I got exactly what your requirements are.
Let me know and I'll delete the answer if I didn't understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve using function objects.
Please find code below:

```
struct value1
{
    const int item;
    value1( int n ) : item(n) { }
};

struct value2 : public value1
{
    value2() : value1(55) { };
};

template <class T>
class property
{
public:
    property();
    void operator() (T i)
    {
        item = i.item;
    }
    void print();
private:
    int item;
};

template <class T>
property<T>::property()  { }

template <class T>
void property<T>::print()
{
    cout << item << endl;
}

int main()
{
    property<value2> *y = new property<value2>();
    (*y)(value2());
    y->print();
   return 0;
}
```